# Google apps script for Gmail - broken email from inbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I have developed a Gmail add-on.
In that I will get the list of emails in from, to, cc and bcc with the help of [GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message) class.
like for from email , [GmailMessage.getFrom()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getfrom)
for to email, [GmailMessage.getTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getto)
In the documentation it is stated that it will return an email as string but it is not clearly mentioned anywhere about the format of that string.
Sometimes I'm getting in the format of  `Name of the account<accountEmail@gmail.com>`
and sometimes in the format of `<accountEmail@gmail.com>` and sometimes only name will be available without the email ID of the recepient.
Sometimes it also includes double quotes on the email like `Name of the account<"accountEmail@gmail.com">`

Can someone tell is there a way to get the exact email address and name separately from Gmail using Google apps script?
Or suggest some ways to parse the email from GmailMessage class and get email address and name separately

Comment: Note that this is not an inconsistency - [the standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822) defines several equally *valid* ways of specifying an address (and therefore several `from` header formats). `name <address@domain.tld>` is one of them. `GmailApp` service probably just returns the header without modifications, hence the perceived inconsistency ( not that knowing how to deal with it is not useful - just pointing out what is actually going on here )

Answer (score 1):

I found the the gmail api site [(here)](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) which might come in use if you end up using the code. Although the code is in python so it might not work on google app script, but the only reason to use google apps script is to achieve these results. You also are going to have to know what you are doing when using this(if you want to use google app script, try making a gmail app template then go here to learn the basics [(here)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)  and here for further documentation [(here)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail))

Replace `CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION` value with the location of your `client_secrets.json` file.

```
import logging
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.client import FlowExchangeError
from apiclient.discovery import build
# ...


# Path to client_secrets.json which should contain a JSON document such as:
#   {
#     "web": {
#       "client_id": "[[YOUR_CLIENT_ID]]",
#       "client_secret": "[[YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET]]",
#       "redirect_uris": [],
#       "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
#       "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
#     }
#   }
CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION = '<PATH/TO/CLIENT_SECRETS.JSON>'
REDIRECT_URI = '<YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI>'
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    # Add other requested scopes.
]

class GetCredentialsException(Exception):
  """Error raised when an error occurred while retrieving credentials.

  Attributes:
    authorization_url: Authorization URL to redirect the user to in order to
                       request offline access.
  """

  def __init__(self, authorization_url):
    """Construct a GetCredentialsException."""
    self.authorization_url = authorization_url


class CodeExchangeException(GetCredentialsException):
  """Error raised when a code exchange has failed."""


class NoRefreshTokenException(GetCredentialsException):
  """Error raised when no refresh token has been found."""


class NoUserIdException(Exception):
  """Error raised when no user ID could be retrieved."""


def get_stored_credentials(user_id):
  """Retrieved stored credentials for the provided user ID.

  Args:
    user_id: User's ID.
  Returns:
    Stored oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials if found, None otherwise.
  Raises:
    NotImplemented: This function has not been implemented.
  """
  # TODO: Implement this function to work with your database.
  #       To instantiate an OAuth2Credentials instance from a Json
  #       representation, use the oauth2client.client.Credentials.new_from_json
  #       class method.
  raise NotImplementedError()


def store_credentials(user_id, credentials):
  """Store OAuth 2.0 credentials in the application's database.

  This function stores the provided OAuth 2.0 credentials using the user ID as
  key.

  Args:
    user_id: User's ID.
    credentials: OAuth 2.0 credentials to store.
  Raises:
    NotImplemented: This function has not been implemented.
  """
  # TODO: Implement this function to work with your database.
  #       To retrieve a Json representation of the credentials instance, call the
  #       credentials.to_json() method.
  raise NotImplementedError()


def exchange_code(authorization_code):
  """Exchange an authorization code for OAuth 2.0 credentials.

  Args:
    authorization_code: Authorization code to exchange for OAuth 2.0
                        credentials.
  Returns:
    oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials instance.
  Raises:
    CodeExchangeException: an error occurred.
  """
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION, ' '.join(SCOPES))
  flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI
  try:
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(authorization_code)
    return credentials
  except FlowExchangeError, error:
    logging.error('An error occurred: %s', error)
    raise CodeExchangeException(None)


def get_user_info(credentials):
  """Send a request to the UserInfo API to retrieve the user's information.

  Args:
    credentials: oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials instance to authorize the
                 request.
  Returns:
    User information as a dict.
  """
  user_info_service = build(
      serviceName='oauth2', version='v2',
      http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
  user_info = None
  try:
    user_info = user_info_service.userinfo().get().execute()
  except errors.HttpError, e:
    logging.error('An error occurred: %s', e)
  if user_info and user_info.get('id'):
    return user_info
  else:
    raise NoUserIdException()


def get_authorization_url(email_address, state):
  """Retrieve the authorization URL.

  Args:
    email_address: User's e-mail address.
    state: State for the authorization URL.
  Returns:
    Authorization URL to redirect the user to.
  """
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION, ' '.join(SCOPES))
  flow.params['access_type'] = 'offline'
  flow.params['approval_prompt'] = 'force'
  flow.params['user_id'] = email_address
  flow.params['state'] = state
  return flow.step1_get_authorize_url(REDIRECT_URI)


def get_credentials(authorization_code, state):
  """Retrieve credentials using the provided authorization code.

  This function exchanges the authorization code for an access token and queries
  the UserInfo API to retrieve the user's e-mail address.
  If a refresh token has been retrieved along with an access token, it is stored
  in the application database using the user's e-mail address as key.
  If no refresh token has been retrieved, the function checks in the application
  database for one and returns it if found or raises a NoRefreshTokenException
  with the authorization URL to redirect the user to.

  Args:
    authorization_code: Authorization code to use to retrieve an access token.
    state: State to set to the authorization URL in case of error.
  Returns:
    oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials instance containing an access and
    refresh token.
  Raises:
    CodeExchangeError: Could not exchange the authorization code.
    NoRefreshTokenException: No refresh token could be retrieved from the
                             available sources.
  """
  email_address = ''
  try:
    credentials = exchange_code(authorization_code)
    user_info = get_user_info(credentials)
    email_address = user_info.get('email')
    user_id = user_info.get('id')
    if credentials.refresh_token is not None:
      store_credentials(user_id, credentials)
      return credentials
    else:
      credentials = get_stored_credentials(user_id)
      if credentials and credentials.refresh_token is not None:
        return credentials
  except CodeExchangeException, error:
    logging.error('An error occurred during code exchange.')
    # Drive apps should try to retrieve the user and credentials for the current
    # session.
    # If none is available, redirect the user to the authorization URL.
    error.authorization_url = get_authorization_url(email_address, state)
    raise error
  except NoUserIdException:
    logging.error('No user ID could be retrieved.')
  # No refresh token has been retrieved.
  authorization_url = get_authorization_url(email_address, state)
  raise NoRefreshTokenException(authorization_url)
```